# JSF + Seam + a4j Triggering one component ajax from a different component event

Tags: ajax, jsf, seam

I wanted to ask just what title says:
say we have a inputtext and a button. Well, I wanted to submit an ajax request in the inputtext when button is clicked.

for example, from the inputtext perspective, I want to achive something like this:

```
<h:inputtext>
   <a4j:support event="button.onclick"/>
<h:inputtext>
<h:button id="button">
```

or, from the button perspective:

```
<h:inputtext id="input"/> 
<h:button id="button">
   <a4j:support event="onclick" action="input.submit"/>
</h:button>
```

Don't know if there exist an easy way to get this done.

thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally get this done by means of `<a4j:jsFunction>` 
[a4j:jsFunction](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/a4j_jsFunction.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a simple form submit, I think both approach are wrong, as long as you put your inputtext and button properly in a form, the form will automatically submit whatever you have in this form including user's input in inputtext when you click the button. There is no need to do something like `input.submit` yourself. (and it's not correct, either)

For the following case, you will see the setInputValue() of managed bean being invoked when you click your button.

```
<h:inputtext id="input" value=#{bean.inputValue}/>

public void setInputValue(String inputValue){
    this.inputValue = inputValue;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering!
I don't want to submit a form, I have other components I didn't specify in the sample code drafts above. I need to trigger an ajax request just for the inputtext, but, the thing is that I need to trigger it from another component, not for example from the 'onblur'  in the inputtext itself, but for example from an 'onclick' action in a button

Answer (score 0):

Try using

Richfaces Region component to limit your request to diffrent regions.

http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/a4j_region.html

Comment: Thanks! I tried this too, don't know if it was in the right way but didn't work. I finally got this done using a4j:function.